# How to call a custom JavaScript alert box from php

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code.

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("This is a popup box")';
echo '</script>';
```

This works fine as intended. However, I would like to use a custom and aesthetically pleasing pop-up box. So I went online and saw some nice JS libraries such as [Alertify](http://alertifyjs.com/), [BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com) and a few others. I included the JS scripts (JQuery,Boostrap, library scripts) and their CSS files on the top of the PHP file. Now I use the same method as previously.

[image]

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo ' alertify.alert("This is the default alert!")';
echo '</script>';
```

For some reason this never works, I get the following error. Can anyone tell what I may be doing wrong, or what is the correct way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Is the PHP that makes your script tag above your script tag for alertify? By the way, you would have to have alertify on your Server, since that's a relative path.

Comment: try loading your `script` after the `CSS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the DOM to load all the files (in this case your external script) - try this:

```js
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {';
echo ' alertify.alert("This is the default alert!")';
echo '});';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, btw here's a missing ";" on the 4th line but thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yuck. Use a here document or an external script.

Answer (score 1):

You can as well ensure you are loading the CSS and JavaScript files in the following Order. I never have issue following this order.

I.) CSS First

1. BootStrap CSS
2. Other Vendor CSS
3. Your custom CSS

II.) JavaScript second

1. jQuery Js
2. BootStrap Js
3. Other Vendor Js
4. Your Custom Js